# Offset a rectangles position to always have a part of it touching the along the circles circumference

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi I have object which I position along the edge of a circle. I have achieved this with the code below.

```
private Point GetPosNew(double degrees, double radius)
        {
            double Radains = Deg2Rad(degrees - 90);
            Point coords;

            if (degrees == 0)
            {
                coords.Y -= radius;
            }
            else if (degrees == 90)
            {
                coords.X += radius;
            }
            else if (degrees == 180)
            {
                coords.Y += radius;
            }
            else if (degrees == 270)
            {
                coords.X -= radius;
            }
            else
            {
                if (degrees > 0 && degrees < 90)
                {
                    coords.X += radius * Math.Sin(Deg2Rad(degrees));
                    coords.Y -= radius * Math.Cos(Deg2Rad(degrees));
                }
                else if (degrees > 90 && degrees < 180)
                {
                    coords.X += radius * Math.Cos(Deg2Rad(degrees-90));
                    coords.Y += radius * Math.Sin(Deg2Rad(degrees-90));
                }
                else if (degrees > 180 && degrees < 270)
                {
                    coords.X -= radius * Math.Sin(Deg2Rad(degrees-180));
                    coords.Y += radius * Math.Cos(Deg2Rad(degrees-180));
                }
                else if (degrees > 270 && degrees < 360)
                {
                    coords.X -= radius * Math.Cos(Deg2Rad(degrees-270));
                    coords.Y -= radius * Math.Sin(Deg2Rad(degrees-270));
                }
            }

            return coords;
        }
```

the issue I am having is the object has a different width and height and it needs to be on the inside of the circle so I cant use the center point of the object to place it. it always need to be touching the inside of the circle with a part of the rectangle.

[image: Text]

So the question is how would I apply a offset to add and subtract from the Coords.

Sorry if this doesn't make sense I struggled to think of how to word this to get the point across.
I'll try to answer any questions the best I can.

Comment: What defines the angle? Are you working angle to point or point on circle back... or what? How accurate does it have to be? How many calculations will you be doing and is speed significant? Is your purpose significant to an acceptable answer?

Comment: I am just entering a random angle between 0-360 and it will generate a coordinate from the origin point 0,0 to place the object on the view. the amount of calculations will vary as it will just add another point to the circle when a button is pressed. I am not so pressed on a speedy solution. Just looking for a way to take the point on the circle i generate and offset it inward depending on the width and height of the object being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an angle alpha, that your circle is R radius, centered in (0,0) and that you put the center of your rectangle at r distance of the center of the circle (the unknown variable). Assuming again your rectangle's half width is w and half height h, you have the coordinates of the 4 points constituting your rectangle:

```
x = r * cos(alpha) + w, y = r * sin(alpha) + h
x = r * cos(alpha) - w, y = r * sin(alpha) + h
x = r * cos(alpha) + w, y = r * sin(alpha) - h
x = r * cos(alpha) - w, y = r * sin(alpha) - h
```

You just need to check the equation `x² + y² = R²` for each point, leading to a quadratic equation in `r` variable.

Comment: From the four solutions choose the smallest r.

Comment: @Clemens: indeed, this part was missing.

Comment: do you mean R or r?

Comment: @Cameron the smallest r. R is given, it is the radius of your circle.